# Convert length of time to appropriate unit

Tags: java, time

I have a time, in seconds, which has the possibility to be very large. I wish to convert said time into the "appropriate" rounded, readable format.

I already have code which achieves this, however it's not very efficient (and contains a whole bunch of magic numbers):

```
    String readable = decayTime + " minutes";
    if(decayTime > 60)
    {
        decayTime /= 60;
        readable = decayTime + " hours";

        if(decayTime > 24)
        {
            decayTime /= 24;
            readable = decayTime + " days";

            if(decayTime > 365)
            {
                decayTime /= 365;
                readable = decayTime + " years";

                if(decayTime > 1000000)
                {
                    decayTime /= 1000000;
                    readable = decayTime + "mn years";

                    if(decayTime > 1000)
                    {
                        decayTime /= 1000;
                        readable = decayTime + "bn years"; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Apart from switching out the magic numbers, I can't personally think how to make it better.

What I am asking is essentially what would be a better approach to this, or is there something in-built which could help?

Edit: moved to here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139970/convert-length-of-time-to-appropriate-unit

Comment: Take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you're using Java 8, use the classes in the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package, specifically [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)

Comment: You should also be doing the reassignment to `readable` only in an `else` block, so that you aren't doing more concatenation than necessary, since all you do is discard the value at each higher step.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'll post it over there, thanks.

Comment: @4castle I'll look at that, thanks. I'll also look at reducing assignment if the code review guys don't come up with something better!

Comment: use `JodaTime` or `java.time` in case of Java8

Comment: @Antoniosss Can you be more specific?  I couldn't find a good way to do this with the `java.time` offerings, but I might have missed something.

Comment: @DavidWallace `java.time` is an Java 8's adaptaion of `JodaTime`. You can use `Period` class to calculate how many years, months, days, minutes, seconds last between 2 given points in time. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html

Comment: No, `Period` only does years, months and days - it doesn't do hours minutes and seconds.  Moreover, it doesn't contain the logic that OP requires - that is, whether to show the interval as an approximate number of days, of years, or whatever.  This question is all about how to do this particular `if/else` logic - and `Period` doesn't do this at all.  I can't find any class in `java.time` that _does_ do the kind of thing that OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Duration but it doesn't convert to years.

```
Duration.ofSeconds(decayTime).toNanos();
Duration.ofSeconds(decayTime).toMillis();
Duration.ofSeconds(decayTime).toMinutes();
Duration.ofSeconds(decayTime).toHours();
Duration.ofSeconds(decayTime).toDays();
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html

Another option is:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(decayTime);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros(decayTime);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(decayTime);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(decayTime);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(decayTime);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(decayTime);
```

For the year you could use some hack like:

```
Long.parseLong(new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY").format(new Date(Duration.ofSeconds(decayTime).toMillis())));
```

But I **strongly don't recomend** it.

Comment: Unfortunately, those `Duration` methods are for the *total* time as minutes or hours or such. In Java 8 this class inexplicably omitted getter methods for the parts (hours *and* minutes *and* seconds and such). Java 9 remedies this with additional getter methods: `toDaysPart`, `toHoursPart`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

## ISO 8601

FYI, the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines sensible non-ambiguous formats for date-time values. This includes a compact way to [represent a span of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`

The `P` marks the beginning, the `T` separates the years-months-days from hours-minutes-seconds.

Examples:

- `PT1H30M` = An hour and a half.
- `P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S` = three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds

## java.time

The java.time classes in Java 8 and later use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing or generating strings to represent date-time values.

The java.time classes include a pair of classes for spans of time. Both can parse/generate this ISO 8601 format.

- [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) for years, months, and days.
- [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) for days, hours, minutes, seconds, and fraction of second.

Your scale of minutes to billions of years is too extreme for this obviously, but this does suit the more mundane business world outside of science.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are useful for shorter lengths of time, but without some ugly hacks and likely a block of code less useful for the longer periods I require. @David Wallace over on Code Review [gave an answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139970/convert-length-of-time-to-appropriate-unit/139972#139970) which used a `TreeMap`:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TimeFormatter {

    private NavigableMap<Long,String> timeUnits = new TreeMap<>();

    public TimeFormatter() {
        timeUnits.put(Long.MIN_VALUE, " is not a valid argument");
        timeUnits.put(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(1), " seconds");
        timeUnits.put(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1), " minutes");
        timeUnits.put(TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1), " hours");
        timeUnits.put(TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1), " days");
        timeUnits.put(TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(365), " years");
        timeUnits.put(TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(365 * 1000000L), " million years");
        timeUnits.put(TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(365 * 1000000L * 1000), " billion years");
    }

    public String format(long milliseconds) {
        Map.Entry<Long,String> unitBelow = timeUnits.floorEntry(milliseconds);

        int time = (int) (milliseconds / unitBelow.getKey());
        String formatted = time + unitBelow.getValue();

        if(time == 1 && unitBelow.getKey() < 1000000L) formatted = formatted.substring(0, formatted.length()-1); //Remove plural

        return formatted;
    }
}
```

I have changed David's answer to use TimeUnit to cut down on the number of magic numbers, as well as dealing with plurals.

EDIT: Some magic numbers do obviously still exist, and actually the code required to deal with larger units are not as bad as I expected.